# Load testing with 100s or MAC clients machines simultaneously

Tags: macos, client, performance-testing, load-testing

I am working on creating a test bed for load testing of network authentication device. The server will be getting 100 to 1000 simultaneous request from client and response time will be collected and analysed.

But issue i am facing is that this a mac OS based scenario. All my client machines needs to be MAC. This means I need 100s of mac machines which is not realistically possible. Is there a way to simulate/emulate mac OS environment,Apart from creating virtual machines. OR any tool which can generate a req behaving like a different client machine all together. 
I am even fine with any code library that can help with the simulation

I have explored dockers but seems like Mac OS dockers are not supported yet.
I am not a proficient mac user any help or pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this is a **network** authentication device it receives authentication requests using a [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) so you need to inspect the [network packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet) using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and identify the data which allows your service to distinguish the operating system of connecting user.

For example when it comes to [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol the only way of identifying the operating system of the client is reading the information from the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header which can easily be substituted as [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) are being send as plain text.

You might also want to implement some form of [IP spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/) so each outgoing authentication request would have its own unique IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I think simultaneity is an issue here as well.   As you note MACs, this implies actual users.  Actual user populations arrive and depart chaotically, not tied to a clock tick.   Even when you have a spot sale, the population arrives not all at once, but in a short window of time.   Consider all load staged to a point, then released with a random sleep() interval tied to the observable arrival model for your authentication solution.

You mention MAC.  Ask yourself, how does the backend authentication solution know or care that a MAC is involved.   It is likely somewhere in the protocol level handshake for authentication.   So long as you present the same handshake as your MAC, then you will be fine even if no MAC is in the loop.